# Tzitzis and Sports

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, sport-athletics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tzitzis while exercising?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/170/tzitzis-while-exercising)

Should one take them off during sports? I've heard lots about this (both ways), but I want to know what Halacha says.